# Python: How to pip install opencv2 with specific version 2.4.9?

Tags: python, opencv, pip, package

I know that I could `pip install opencv-python` which installs opencv3, but is there a separate command or name for opencv specific version such as 2.4.9?

If not, how can I specify which version to install?

Thanks.

Comment: In Python3, try `python3 -m pip install --user opencv-python`

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Via `pip` you can specify the package version to install using the following:

```
pip install opencv-python==2.4.9
```

However, that package does not seem to be available on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python).

A little trick for checking available versions:

`pip install opencv-python==`

Which returns:

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python== 
(from versions: 3.1.0.0, 3.1.0.1, 3.1.0.2, 3.1 .0.3, 3.1.0.5, 3.2.0.6, 3.2.0.7) No matching distribution found for opencv-python==`

Comment: 2.4.9 is not a matching requirement for the versions available to me. Ideas?

Comment: so how do we install opencv version 2 for python ?

Comment: Doing what you say results in the following error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python==2.4.9 (from versions: 3.1.0.5, 3.2.0.6, 3.2.0.7, 3.2.0.8, 3.3.0.9, 3.3.0.10, 3.3.1.11, 3.4.0.12, 3.4.0.14, 3.4.1.15, 3.4.2.16, 3.4.2.17, 3.4.3.18, 3.4.4.19)
No matching distribution found for opencv-python==2.4.9

Comment: or if you want to see latest version `sudo apt-cache policy opencv-python`

Answer (score 42):

Easy and simple

- Prerequisites

  - pip install matplotlib
  - pip install numpy
- Final step

  - pip install opencv-python

Specific version
* Final step
     * opencv-python==2.4.9

Comment: Why would someone downvote this ?! doesn't it actually work? I'll upvote this.

Comment: People do not understand that I'm simply trying to help.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can explain why others might have: You're answer is suggesting exactly what the question states didn't work: `pip install opencv-python`. Therefore this is not answering the question (how to install OpenCV version 2.4.9 (or similar), not the latest version). However the question title obviously will lead people here who want to use the module cv2 (which is included in any OpenCV version > 2.0, also 3.4) and for those you provided the most straightforward way... therefore it arguably is still a good answer, at least to the question title ;)

Comment: @AbdulSheikh when I type `pip install opencv-python==3.6.4` it throws an error `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python==3.6.4 (from versions: 3.1.0.5, 3.2.0.6, 3.2.0.7, 3.2.0.8, 3.3.0.9, 3.3.0.10, 3.3.1.11, 3.4.0.12)
No matching distribution found for opencv-python==3.6.4`

Answer (score 15):

There's another easy way, you can type in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

[Install OpenCV-Python in Ubuntu](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html)

After installing it, you can use opencv version 2.4 in both c++ and python.

But I recommend you should use opencv 3.2.0 and opencv-contrib, it gives more features

Hope this can help!

Comment: Some distributions have ppa of opencv, some did not. You must add PPA of opencv base on your OS distribution in order to install this. Or you can install Anaconda to resolve this. It has OpenCV 3.2.0

Comment: Try this `sudo apt-get install python-opencv`

Comment: This does not work anymore as it will install opencv 3.2.0

Comment: may be your distribution is upgraded, so that it can only find 3.2.0. Or you could install anaconda instead

Answer (score 9):

**cv2 vs. "opencv3"**

To get a potential misunderstanding out of the way:
The python OpenCV module is named and imported via `import cv2` in all versions > 2.0, including > 3.0. If you want to work with `cv2`, installing OpenCV versions > 3 is fine - unless you're looking for specific compatibility with older versions or are a fan of the 2.4.x versions. The switch from 2.4.x to 3.x was in 2015 and in terms of features, speed and transparency, it makes much sense to use the newer versions. You can read [here](https://opencv.org/opencv-3-0.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29587529/6409572) about major differences. 2.4.x versions are still supported though, [current release](https://opencv.org/releases.html) is 2.4.13.5.

**Installing a specific version, e.g. OpenCV 2.4.9**

That said:
If you want to install a specific version that neither `pip install opencv-python==2.4.X`, `sudo apt-get install opencv` nor `conda install opencv=2.4.x` provide (as explained by other answers here), you can always install from sources. In the [sourceforge repository](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/?source=navbar) you can find all major versions for each operating system. Although for unxeperienced users this might be scary, it is well explained in some tutorials. E.g. [here](http://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) for 2.4.9 on Ubuntu 14.04. Or [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) is the official Linux install doc for the latest release 2.4.13.5.

In essence, the install process boils down to:

1. install dependencies, refer to docs (e.g. [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html)) for required packages
2. get sources from [OpenCVs sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/?source=navbar)

   e.g. `wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.4.9/opencv-2.4.9.zip`
3. unzip sources and prepare build by creating build directory and running cmake

   ```
   mkdir build
   cd build
   cmake (... your build options ...)
   ```
4. build in the created build directory with:

   ```
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

Answer (score 6):

You can also do it using [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/):

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv=2.4.9
```

Comment: However, this version requires libpng 1.5.x while conda only provides libpng>1.6.x now.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using windows os, you can download your desired opencv unofficial windows binary from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), and type 
something like `pip install opencv_python-2.4.13.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` in the directory of binary file.

Comment: Tried it and got "opencv_python-2.4.13.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Comment: @CIsForCookies This works me.  Do you download the right  version for (32- bit vs 64 bit)?

Comment: i tried both 32 and 64 bit options but i got the same error about not a supported wheel on this platform.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
pip install opencv==2.4.9
```

Comment: That will install the latest release of the package, rather than OpenCV 2. The command was also already mentioned by the OP.

Comment: i tried this command and i get following error  Collecting opencv==2.4.9
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv==2.4.9 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv==2.4.9

Comment: @AzamRafique try a python distributor, i personally recommend Anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

```
python3.6 -m pip install opencv-python
```

will install cv2 in linux in branch python3.6

Answer (score 2):

```
python -m pip install opencv-python
```

which will install opencv based on your current python

Answer (score 1):

If you're a Windows user, opencv can be installed using pip, like this:

```
pip install opencv-python==<python version>

ex - pip install opencv-python==3.6
```

If you're a Linux user:

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

At the same time, opencv can be installed using conda like this...

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv=3.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Python packages are to be downloaded and installed to their default locations.

1.1. Python-2.7.x.

1.2. Numpy.

1.3. Matplotlib (Matplotlib is optional, but recommended since we use it a lot in our tutorials).

Install all packages into their default locations. Python will be installed to C:/Python27/.

After installation, open Python IDLE. Enter import numpy and make sure Numpy is working fine.

Download latest OpenCV release from sourceforge site and double-click to extract it.

Goto opencv/build/python/2.7 folder.

Copy cv2.pyd to C:/Python27/lib/site-packeges.

Open Python IDLE and type following codes in Python terminal.

> > > import cv2
> > >       print cv2.**version**
> > >       If the results are printed out without any errors, congratulations !!! You have installed OpenCV-Python successfully.

https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html

Answer (score 0):

The following command line `pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.16` works properly. Use one of the versions presented to you. May be:

```
3.1.0.5, 3.2.0.6, 3.2.0.7, 3.2.0.8, 3.3.0.9, 3.3.0.10, 3.3.1.11, or 3.4.0.12, etc.
```

To make sure, you can see my screenshot.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w7Jr.png)