# Install opencv on Google App Engine Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, google-app-engine

Hi I installed on a Google App Engine Python 2.7, opencv using

```
pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt
```

requirements.txt is:

```
Flask==0.12.1
Werkzeug==0.12.2
Opencv_python==3.3.0.10
```

Install worked, I can use other libraries, but when I try to import opencv on code, it throws the next exception:

```
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/tcarrillof/python-docs-hello-world/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/home/tcarrillof/python-docs-hello-world/lib/cv2/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/request_environment.py", line 126, in __getitem__
    return self._request.environ[key]
KeyError: 'PATH'
```

Is it there something I need to configure?, Any help is welcome in advance :)

Note:

app.yaml is:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

and appengine_config.py is:

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'lib'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is less something you need to configure, and more something to abandon. OpenCV won't run in the standard App Engine environment. OpenCV is a big chunk of C++ (with Python wrappers). App Engine only supports libraries that are pure Python unless they're on the list in  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

If you need OpenCV, consider using the Flex environment.

Comment: Another option could be to use [Google Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) if it provides the needed functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) which might make life simpler

You can see in [Support Python in Cloud Functions](https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/299943--google-cloud-platform/suggestions/18981547-support-python-in-cloud-functions) the last comment you can find a link to this [cloud-functions-python](https://github.com/MartinSahlen/cloud-functions-python?#readme)

You can just list `opencv` as one libraries required along with other libraries such as `numpy` and `matplotlib` generally used along with any others you might actually want to use.

How to install `OpenCV` using pip here's a nice answer I found on [stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439443/can-i-pip-install-opencv2-for-python/44439955#44439955)