# Can't import cv2 from downloaded opencv library

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I need to run a script which uses SIFT, with PyCharm. I must use the OpenCv 2.4.13, but I can't install previous version than OpenCV 3.x using the PyCharm package installer. So I downloaded the OpenCV 2.4.13 folder, put it in my project folder and created a new Virtualenv Environment, adding the path to the OpenCV folder to the Python interpreter for that Virtualenv Environment, but I still can't import cv2 getting the error "no module named cv2".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you install it? Downloading a folder does not mean installing it.
I suggest you try following the steps proposed as answers of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439443/can-i-pip-install-opencv2-for-python and see if that solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Download the .whl file of the opencv version you need from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv). And in the pycharm terminal run the command:

```
pip install "path to the downloaded wheel file"
```

However it seems opencv is only available for python 2.7 . You might have to switch python versions if you are using python 3.x