# Failed to import a module

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, ubuntu, python-imaging-library

I try to use ImageGrab (open-cv function)

OS: lubuntu

First, I did: `sudo apt-get install python-opencv`.
Installation went successfuly. 
Then I tried to do: `from PIL import ImageGrab`. But at this point I got the following ImportError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/user/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageGrab.py", line 26, in <module> import _grabscreen
ImportError: No module named _grabscreen
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Looks like a dependency is missing.  Does open-cv support py2.7?  [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439443/can-i-pip-install-opencv2-for-python)

Comment: Looks like you need to install the Pillow module

Comment: You need to install Pillow before you can import from it. Something like `pip install pillow`

Comment: @jhomr I did but same error.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I did , same error

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately - ImageGrab only works with Windows

Alternative: pyscreenshot