# I am unable to install opencv

Tags: python, opencv, pip, conda

I have used the command pip install opencv-python. I am getting the error when I am downloading.[This is the error I am getting and there is more lines of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q9m6.png)

[This is the final error I got when the command stopped working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MZKN.png)

Comment: Hi, please include more photos of the errors, especially near the bottom of the error message, that's ususally where the important ones are.

Comment: Also check that your pip is up to date, too.

Comment: Apparently, your virtual environment is using the recently released version of Python i.e. 3.10 which seems to be incompatible with `numpy  1.19.3`.

Comment: Do you have multiple python versions installed? Also make sure you've set your environment variables properly. Also download the version of OpenCV same as that of latest python version in your system.

Comment: I have added the picture @dsillman2000

Comment: Which version should I use to make it compatible @sgarizvi

Comment: @Pam My pip version is up to date

Comment: @HIMANSHUPANDEY How to check whether we have multiple python versions installed

Comment: Check this Directory on your PC : C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python 
       Also check this Stack Overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439443/python-how-to-pip-install-opencv2-with-specific-version-2-4-9

Comment: @ISHAGUPTA... `Python 3.8` works fine for me.

Comment: @ISHAGUPTA please don't post screenshots of erros. Instead copy-paste the error message into your question.

Comment: @dsillman2000 please don't encourage posting of error messages as screenshots. Check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using python 3.10 in your environment. Since it is so new, no pre-built binaries are available for opencv-python and it tries to download source code and compile it on the fly, which fails, because the library is large and has complex dependencies.

What can you do?

You can check [the pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#files) and see that the latest whl for win64 is for cp39, so python 3.9. So you could do

```
 conda install python=3.9 #install python 3.9 in your current env
 pip install opencv-python
```

this should now pull the `opencv_python-4.5.4.58-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl` and install that.

Even better would be however, to simply have `conda` handle that for you:

```
 conda install -c conda-forge py-opencv
```